# Code First from Database, define virtual names for foreign keys

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

The `Request` table has 3 columns `CreatedBy`, `ModifiedBy`, `ClosedBy` and they have foreign key constraints to `User` on `Username`

When I use the Code First from Database to generate the models, in the `Request.cs` model class, it names the foreign tables like `public virtual User User`, `public virtual User User1`, `public virtual User User2`.

Is there a way to specify it to create `public virtual User UserCreatedBy`, `public virtual User UserModifiedBy`, `public virtual User UserClosedBy` instead of manually renaming them?

Comment: You can customize the T4 templates used in reverse engineering, but if this is going to be code first moving forward I don't see the issue.

Answer (score 4):

The "Code First from Database" reverse engineering tool supplied by the Entity Framework team is a bit simplistic in it's wizard form. Although you *can* edit the templates it uses, it's not straightforward. Luckily there is a third party (zero cost) alternative - the [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838/view/Reviews/2)

This visual studio extension is way better than the generator supplied by the Entity Framework team, and provides many simple ways to control the generated POCO classes. If I remember correctly, that includes the option to name navigation properties to match the name of the foreign key property.

There used to be a link on the gallery page to an excellent demonstration video which you should watch.

Unfortunately I'm using Oracle which the tool doesn't support :-(